# Why my CPU are not running 100% while I'm using multiprocessing?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm learning python multiprocessing and I tried this code :

```
def f(name):
    n = 0
    print('running ', name)
    for i in range(1000):
        for j in range(1000):
            for k in range(100):
                n += 1
    print(n)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tab = []
    for i in range(10):
        p = Process(target=f, args=(i,))
        p.start()
        tab.append(p)
    for t in tab:
        t.join()
```

It worked well, and I saw in the monitor that CPU were all running 100%.

But when I switched to my application, which is using a shared variable for multiprocessing, I saw that CPU were all running at 40-50% and execution times are worst than without multiprocessing.

```
def repeat_optimization(self, cycle, nb_cycles, res):
        start = time.time()
        res['a'].append(a())
        res['b'].append(b())
        end = time.time()
        print("Benchmark iteration : " + str(cycle + 1) + "/" + str(nb_cycles) + " completed in " + str(round(end - start, 2)) + "s")

def parallelize_repeat_optimization(self, nb_cycles):
        manager = Manager()
        res = manager.dict()
        res['a'] = []
        res['b'] = []
        
        tab = []
        for cycle in range(nb_cycles):
            p = Process(target=self.repeat_optimization, args=(cycle, nb_cycles, res))
            p.start()
            tab.append(p)
        for t in tab:
            t.join()
  
        return res
```

What's wrong with my code, since I do not see a main difference with the first example ?

Comment: What do `a` and `b` functions do? It's a very different question if they're doing network I/O or creating memory pressure vs pure CPU. It also matters whether they're native Python code or calling C modules that release the GIL while they work, and potentially do their own parallelization.

Comment: They are also using long loops and hard computation, but not doing network I/O.
How can I know if they are doing their own parallelization ?

Comment: Native loops, not numpy ones?

Comment: It's not easy to know without knowing a priori whether the libraries in use are native Python ones / what their concurrency model is if any.

Comment: I can't answer on what they are exactly doing, I didn't write the code (and it is very long).

Comment: The other thing to keep in mind is serialization overhead. Getting data out of a subprocess is slow.

Comment: What are the reported times?

Comment: More than 600s, while each takes 45s in sequential version.

Comment: How large is `nb_cycles`, and how many cores/threads does your CPU have?

Comment: What's the CPU usage if you replace the calls `a()` and `b()` with `f(cycle)`?

Answer (score 0):

In any multiprocessing situation you will always have higher utilization if each process is completely independent. In this case, there are hidden costs to using a `Manager` to synchronize the two processes. Under the hood, the processes have to communicate with each other to make sure they do not overwrite each others' changes, and this means each process will waste a lot of time waiting for responses from the other process.

Comment: "overwrite each other's changes"? Most multiprocessing modes don't use shared memory at all, so they don't need to coordinate on locking; the overhead is just serialization/deserialization, and that comes into play when data is being passed and out.

Comment: To be clear, the general "multiprocessing adds overhead" statement is true, but if the OP hasn't given enough information to allow details to be given about where and why it's adding overhead on their specific program, their question isn't answerable and should be closed.